# Rails. Undefined method `name' for ["Category1", 1]:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am still not very clear about loops, but this time its even more confusing.

I have **Product** and **Category** models and relations between them **:has_many** and **:belongs_to**.

In my apps navbar I have a dropdown to show categories:

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
    <li><%= link_to cat.name, cat %></li>
 <% end %>
```

(I will move this loop to partial later)

It was working fine, but now I noticed that if I try to use this link `<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>` it throws me that error of Undefined method 'name'... I can't even understand why this link triggers this peace of code:

[image]

**Products_controller.rb**:

```
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @categories = Category.all.map { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
  end
```

**shema.rb**:

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "desc"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do

`@categories = Category.all.map { |c| { name: c.name, id: c.id } }`

And in view

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
    <li><%= link_to cat[:name], cat %></li>
 <% end %
```

Comment: oh you were first, but both answers were not very accurate. I had to target name like an object so like this:  `<li><%= link_to cat[:name], cat %></li>`

Comment: J.D. Yes, fixed my answer

Comment: And besides - do you know why I got that error only with that link? If I navigate app on any other links, all was working fine...

Comment: Yes, because you did `Category.all.map { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] }`,. This made your variable `@categories` not active relation object(array with AR objects), but array, which doesn't have methods that matches names of your attributes. Just do `@categories = Category.all`. After this you can do `cat.name`

Comment: hmmmm... Yes it makes sence, but the thing is that I was using `@categories = Category.all` before and it was not working... But now it does... I am new to Rails :) Thanks for time!

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
<li><%= link_to cat[:name], cat %></li>
```

You have mapped `@categories` to an `Array`, so you need to target the array at the name index. (or `item[:name]` in your case)